# VBA - run-time error 1004: application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to write a basic bit of code in which you can select a range of cells in excel for a macro to then lock the selected range on all worksheets in that workbook but I am getting an error 1004 when trying to run it.

The error is occurring on line ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(UpTo).Range(Rng).Locked = True

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Greg

```
Sub LockRange()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim PW As String
Dim UpTo As Integer, Count As Integer


Set Rng = Selection


PW = Application.InputBox(Title:="Password", Prompt:="Enter Worksheet Password", Type:=2)
Debug.Print PW


Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Debug.Print Count

    For UpTo = 1 To Count
    Debug.Print UpTo
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(UpTo).Unprotect PW
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(UpTo).Range(Rng).Locked = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(UpTo).Protect PW
    Next UpTo
      
End Sub
```

Comment: `Rng` is already a range object with a parent sheet attached, the active sheet.  you will want:  `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(UpTo).Range(Rng.address).Locked = True`

Comment: `For Each Ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` is the normal way to loop over all worksheets.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you :) and thanks BigBen for the loop advice